# Update XML value with multiple namespaces not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have searched a lot of questions for this one but I can't find out what I am missing
I have the following xml and I want to update the **SubmissionFormId**

[image]

I am using the following script but I can't understand why it doesn't work.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS i,'http://schemas.ersl.ie/regsys' AS xs)
update submission_form_schema
SET sub_form_xml.modify('  
  replace value of (/SubmissionForm/SubmissionFormId/text())[1]  
  with ("11519")')
where sub_form_id = 11519
select top 10* from submission_form_schema where sub_form_id = 11519
```

My table is like this

[image]

Any clues or hints on what I should be looking for would be a great help.

Comment: Please show sample xml data as text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use defined `xs:`:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS i
                  ,'http://schemas.ersl.ie/regsys' AS xs)
update submission_form_schema
SET sub_form_xml.modify('  
  replace value of (/xs:SubmissionForm/xs:SubmissionFormId/text())[1]  
  with ("11519")')
where sub_form_id = 11519;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2f7f6d827e29ec5907be50c3baa27b14)**

---

Altertatively using `DEFAULT`:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS i
                  ,DEFAULT 'http://schemas.ersl.ie/regsys')
update submission_form_schema
SET sub_form_xml.modify('  
  replace value of (/SubmissionForm/SubmissionFormId/text())[1]  
  with ("11519")')
where sub_form_id = 11519;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5cebe57e1c9e543342252c80ffebf94d)**

---

Or even omit `XMLNAMESPACES` and use wildcard:

```
update submission_form_schema
SET sub_form_xml.modify('  
  replace value of (/*:SubmissionForm/*:SubmissionFormId/text())[1]  
  with ("11519")')
where sub_form_id = 11519;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5f18475baa4b54c234746f3feaaf3894)**

Answer (score 1):

Can't see the whole xml but the obvious problem is you don't specify the defined prefixes in the `replace value of` expression. It should be

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS i,'http://schemas.ersl.ie/regsys' AS xs)
update submission_form_schema
SET sub_form_xml.modify('  
  replace value of (/xs:SubmissionForm/xs:SubmissionFormId/text())[1]  
  with ("11519")')
where sub_form_id = 11519;
```

Demo:

```
create table submission_form_schema(
  sub_form_id int,
  sub_form_xml xml
);
insert submission_form_schema values
(11519, '<SubmissionForm xmlns="http://schemas.ersl.ie/regsys" xmlns:i="http://schemas.ersl.ie/regsys">
       <SubmissionFormId>22222</SubmissionFormId>
     </SubmissionForm>');

WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS i,'http://schemas.ersl.ie/regsys' AS xs)
update submission_form_schema
SET sub_form_xml.modify('  
  replace value of (/xs:SubmissionForm/xs:SubmissionFormId/text())[1]  
  with ("11519")')
where sub_form_id = 11519;

select *
from submission_form_schema;
```

Returns

```
sub_form_id sub_form_xml
------  --------
11519   <SubmissionForm xmlns="http://schemas.ersl.ie/regsys" xmlns:i="http://schemas.ersl.ie/regsys"><SubmissionFormId>11519</SubmissionFormId></SubmissionForm>
```